# Stuck for over 2 hours during Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, inspiron

I have been installing Ubuntu 18.04 for over 2 hours now and it's still stuck where it started. It is still detecting file systems though the codes do keep moving. Is there anything I could do to make it go faster? I am installing it on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 series that has an Intel Core i7 and 8 GB RAM.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if your computer's hard drive had sector errors it normally wouldn't take that long to install Ubuntu. Also your Dell Inspiron is not an old laptop, so its hard drive is probably in good condition.

The screenshot in your question shows that getting updates took 69 minutes. Either don't select the options in the Ubuntu installer to install third-party codecs and download updates while installing, or if you do select these options install Ubuntu at a time of day when your internet connection is fast.

Comment: i havent done so

Comment: I don't think it is internet speed issue